# jQuery how to allow submit form after stopping it

Tags: jquery

I made a function where using  `e.preventDefault()`I stopped form submitting because I need first to check the values inside. How can I do to allowing submitting after that?

Comment: Your question is not about how to _allow_ to submit the form (you cancelled that, end of the story), but to re-initiate submission: https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're handling form submit event, remove `e.preventDefault()` so you can implement and alternative approach.

You should return `false` when you want to cancel submit and simply continue with normal flow you don't. Example:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    if (!isFormInvalid()) {
        // cancel form submit
        return false;
    }

    // continue with function flow if form is valid
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `e.preventDefault()` on a button, rather than an input with type submit.

So change the `<input type="submit"/>` to a `<button id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>`

Then use an event handler to catch the event, and if it is successful, submit the form with `$('form').submit();`, for example:

```
$('document').on('click','#btnSubmit',function(){
   e.preventDefault()

   //do your error handling
   //if successful
   $('#formId').submit();
}
```